# Incremental renaming files in wget2

Tags: wget, rename, batch-rename

How I can rename files in incremental img001.jpg, img002.jpg,img003.jpg in below.
i tried -o, as i am downloading multiple files from text files, the files gets truncated. -o is building a one large file.

`for f in *.txt; do wget2 --max-threads=2 --tries=2 --timeout=90 -i "$f" -P "${f%.txt}"; done`